# Using the "DisplayCustomization" hook

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I started in Prestashop development for a few days.

I try for a few hours to graft a simple template on the displayCustomization hook.

To do this here is what I did:

1 / Recording the hook in the installation method

```
$this->registerHook('displayCustomization')
```

2 / Definition of the display method in the main file of my module

```
public function hookDisplayCustomization($params){
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'custom.tpl');
}
```

3 / Creating the template file in modules \ mymodule \ views \ templates \ hook \ custom.tpl

```
<!-- Block custom -->
<div id="mymodule_block_custom" class="block">
    <div class="block_content">  
        <p> hello world </p>  
    </div> 
</div> 
<!-- /Block custom -->
```

Unfortunately, when I go on a product page with the customization enabled nothing is displayed ...

Besides, should it be activated?

Of course I tried to reinstall the module, reset it etc.

Comment: Are you sure that you have such a hook in your theme's code?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderGrosul , yes is an native feature in prestashop.

Comment: And in which file is it invoked?

Comment: i dont no .....

Answer (score 0):

This hook is used for cart displaying but not for product page and an invocation is in **classes/Product.php**, also it works only if a costomiztion field was added within the module and it doesn't display default fields' types. If you just want to add something to your product page you better to create your own hook and use it. To do this register it with your module

`$this->registerHook('displayCustomizationNew')`

then define your hook

```
public function hookDisplayCustomizationNew($params){
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'custom.tpl');
}
```

and then invoke it in your product page within

`{h='displayCustomizationNew'}`

for example somwhere in a product.tpl

Comment: Thank you for your relevant response.
My need is to add a selection field option to choose a value and so found in the order. 
Do you have an idea of ​​how to proceed?
Thank you